# Google Ads oauth2l fetching a refresh token reports missing 'type' field in credentials

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-ads-api

I am following Google Ads documentation to fetch a refresh token. I have got to this step:
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/make-first-call#fetch_a_refresh_token

```
oauth2l fetch --credentials credentials.json --scope adwords \
    --output_format refresh_token
```

When I run the above command I get the error `missing 'type' field in credentials`

I found answers similar to this: https://github.com/GeneralElectric/GABeat/issues/2

So I tried adding `"type": "service_account"` to the json file but then I get this error instead: `"private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated"`

Below is the `credentials.json` file (after I added the "type" field). The original was downloaded during this step of the Google Ads documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/oauth-cloud-project#id-secret

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "web": {
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "javascript_origins": [
      "https://XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if `oauth2l` only executes a three-legged OAuth2 flow when a [`localhost` redirect URL is included](https://github.com/google/oauth2l/blob/55ad5ab53d7239437b363e9998106c3b3119f0da/main.go#L378) in the credentials file and gives a somewhat misleading error message if that's not the case.

This version of `credentials.json` should work:

```json
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "javascript_origins": [
      "https://XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk"
    ],
    "redirect_uris": [
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note that the flow might then **still not work** at a later stage because you also need to configure the given redirect URLs in the settings of your OAuth client in the GCP console. To fix that, you might need to create a new OAuth application of type "Desktop app" as indicated in the [documentation you linked to](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/get-started/oauth-cloud-project#id-secret).